# How to generate 8 bytes unique random number in python?

Tags: python, random, generator, uuid

Is there any way to generate a unique random number that has *8 bytes* size in python language? I used the UUID library but it has *16 bytes* which are not aligned with my requirement.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean exactly by `unique`? What will you use the number for, and where does the size constraint come from?

Comment: So, there is a frontend and backend part. In the backend, I'm using UUID4 (16 bytes) to generate ID for each user. However, that ID I'm sending it to the frontend and in frontend there's already another UUID that has been used. There's one service which doesn't allow 32 bytes in total. And I'm getting 32 bytes in total; 16 bytes from frontend and 16 bytes from the backend. So, I'm thinking of modifying backend unique ID for each user to 8 bytes.

Comment: Why not use the same UUID in both places?

Comment: This is for GAT server where the UUID is fixed. It's static for the whole application. Can't use it from the backend to the frontend.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.6 and later, this is easy:

- Import the `secrets` module:`import secrets`.
- Generate a random byte sequence with `secrets.token_bytes(8)`. Or, if the string should be readable, use the following which produces a 16-character string out of 8 bytes (`secrets.token_hex(8)`), or a 8-character string out of 4 bytes (`secrets.token_hex(4)`).

---

My comment from July 8 moved here and edited:

In general, random values will not be unique by themselves. You will have to pair the random numbers with other unique information (such as sequentially-assigned row numbers of a database table). However, if you can tolerate the risk of duplicate IDs, note that 20,000 random 8-byte values have a low probability of differing from each other. (For a formula, see the Wikipedia article [Birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).) See my article for [more advice](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Unique_Random_Identifiers) on unique identifiers.

Comment: Hi Peter, will it be unique throughout the course, for example, a unique ID that belongs to each user like that for all 20K users?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use [Linear Congruential Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) which, with proper selection of parameters, produce perfect mapping from u64 to u64. In other words, if you have access to previous 8bytes UUID, you could generate reasonable random next 8bytes UUID WITHOUT REPETITIONS till whole 2<sup>64</sup> space ix exhausted. It could also go backward and forward N steps in O(log(N)).

Code using NumPy, Python 3.7, Anaconda, Win 10 x64

```
#%%
import numpy as np

#%%
class LCG(object):

    UZERO: np.uint64 = np.uint64(0)
    UONE : np.uint64 = np.uint64(1)

    def __init__(self, seed: np.uint64, a: np.uint64, c: np.uint64) -> None:
        self._seed: np.uint64 = np.uint64(seed)
        self._a   : np.uint64 = np.uint64(a)
        self._c   : np.uint64 = np.uint64(c)

    def next(self) -> np.uint64:
        self._seed = self._a * self._seed + self._c
        return self._seed

    def seed(self) -> np.uint64:
        return self._seed

    def set_seed(self, seed: np.uint64) -> np.uint64:
        self._seed = seed

    def skip(self, ns: np.int64) -> None:
        """
        Signed argument - skip forward as well as backward

        The algorithm here to determine the parameters used to skip ahead is
        described in the paper F. Brown, "Random Number Generation with Arbitrary Stride,"
        Trans. Am. Nucl. Soc. (Nov. 1994). This algorithm is able to skip ahead in
        O(log2(N)) operations instead of O(N). It computes parameters
        A and C which can then be used to find x_N = A*x_0 + C mod 2^M.
        """

        nskip: np.uint64 = np.uint64(ns)

        a: np.uint64 = self._a
        c: np.uint64 = self._c

        a_next: np.uint64 = LCG.UONE
        c_next: np.uint64 = LCG.UZERO

        while nskip > LCG.UZERO:
            if (nskip & LCG.UONE) != LCG.UZERO:
                a_next = a_next * a
                c_next = c_next * a + c

            c = (a + LCG.UONE) * c
            a = a * a

            nskip = nskip >> LCG.UONE

        self._seed = a_next * self._seed + c_next


#%%
np.seterr(over='ignore')

a = np.uint64(6364136223846793005)
c = np.uint64(1)

seed = np.uint64(1)

rng64 = LCG(seed, a, c)

print(rng64.next())
print(rng64.next())
print(rng64.next())

#%%
rng64.skip(-3) # back by 3
print(rng64.next())
print(rng64.next())
print(rng64.next())

rng64.skip(-3) # back by 3
rng64.skip(2) # forward by 2
print(rng64.next())
```