# Code for reversing Linear Congruential Generator in python

Tags: python, random, lcg

index 0 of x is the seed, but what if, you want to know the index -1 of x.

I am making a game in python with pygame, and i require help, since i require to use that in world generation

Edit:

x is the random number, index 0 of x is seed

the LCG looks like this

x[i + 1] = (x[i] * mu + inc) % m

m is modulus

inc is increment

mu is multiplier

Comment: What is x? It's unclear what you are talking about. Please provide more context.

Comment: X is the seed, the starting number of the random array

Comment: So your question is, given x[i+1], how to find x[i]?

Comment: yeah, thats the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate 8 bytes unique random number in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62797012/how-to-generate-8-bytes-unique-random-number-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If x<sub>i+1</sub> = x<sub>i</sub> * mu + inc (mod m), then x<sub>i</sub> = (x<sub>i+1</sub> - inc) * mu<sup>−1</sup> (mod m), where mu<sup>−1</sup> is the [modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of mu (mod m). It's a fairly straightforward calculation.

Comment: im a dummy, please tell me if this is the one u said
```def reverse(x,mu,m,inc):

 return(((x - inc) * (mu ** -1)) % m)```

Comment: nevermind i had a problem with the first algorithm since i had a bit off the algorithm so this is in fact correct